# Deleting specific component in v-for array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have below array, that contains a number of columns. Below example contains three columns, but columns can be added/removed dynamically:

```
[['position', '30'], ['position', '60'], ['position', '90']]
```

I am facing issues when deleting the *correct* column (index in array) with Vue.

Consider below snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    columns: [['position', '30'], ['position', '60'], ['position', '90']]
  },
  methods: {
   deleteColumn: function(index) {
     this.columns.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  
  <div v-for="(item, index) in columns" :key="index">
  Column #: {{index}} - <a @click="deleteColumn(index)">Delete me</a>
  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

If you run the above code snippet end try to delete the #1 column, it will actually remove the #2 column (last item of the array). Same goes for #0.

I thought that by providing the `index` to my `deleteColumn` function, I could remove the "right" index from the array.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @oliverbj are the position values unique, or could you add an `id` to each?

Comment: The values are not unique. If needed, the array may be “re-mapped” before render (so yes, and id may be added)

Comment: If you can add an `id` to each, I'd recommend keeping a list of removed ids, and then using a computed property to return a filtered list with the removed ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clicked any item you are removing it in the right way, your index is your key, that's the problem, but is visually, in the logic it's right. Display your position in your template just for you can see it. ANd for me your data it's not in the right way.

```
<div id="app">
     <div v-for="(item, index) in columns" :key="index">
         Column #: {{index}}-{{item.position}} - 
         <a @click="deleteColumn(index)">Delete me</a>
     </div>  
</div>
```

and your script for you can see the change

```
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
  columns: [{position: 30}, {position: 60}, {position: 90}]
 },
 methods: {
  deleteColumn: function(index) {     
    this.columns.splice(index, 1);
  }
 }
})
```

Comment: Any idea on how to remove the “right” item visually?

Comment: change your data and template lie this:

**template** = <div v-for="(item, index) in columns" :key="index">
  Column #: {{index}}-{{item.position}} - <a @click="deleteColumn(index)">Delete me</a> 
  </div>

**script** =   columns: [{position: 30}, {position: 60}, {position: 90}]

Answer (score 2):

Just give them a property name and you are done. Notice what I changed here. Columns is no more a 2D array, but objects. Use `this.$delete(this.columns, index);` to delete the objects.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    columns: {
      '1': {
        position: 30
      },
      '2': {
        position: 60
      },
      '3': {
        position: 90
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deleteColumn: function(index) {
      this.$delete(this.columns, index);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div v-for="(item, index) in columns" :key="index">
    Column #: {{index}} - <a @click="deleteColumn(index)">Delete me</a>

  </div>

</div>
```

```
{
  '1': {
    position: 30
  },
  '2': {
    position: 60
  },
  '3': {
    position: 90
  }
}
```

Here, '1' is a property name and it's value is another object. It's like giving ids to your data.

The format for value of object is this

```
{ property_name : value }
```

Here, value is another object, and in that object, there is another property, named "position" with your corresponding values.

Comment: Ah! Now I just need to figure out how to add the property name.

Comment: Just do `"property_name" : { obj : value }` this just like `position: 90` here position is a property name, but here, "property_name" is another object. @oliverbj

Comment: Would you mind including it in your answer? How I can set the property name to 1, 2 3 etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method reindexes the array, moving all elements after the splice point up or down so that any new inserted values will fit and so that the array indices remain contiguous.  You can see it more clearly if you also display the values of the items in your list:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    columns: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
  },
  methods: {
    deleteColumn: function(index) {
      this.columns.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in columns" :key="index">
  Column #{{index}} = {{item}} - <a @click="deleteColumn(index)" style="cursor:pointer">Delete me</a>      
  </div>
</div>
```

Initially, the snippet above will render like this:

> Column #0 = foo - Delete me
>   Column #1 = bar - Delete me
>   Column #2 = baz - Delete me

If you now click the "Delete me" link on column #0 ("foo"), it will change to:

> Column #0 = bar - Delete me
>   Column #1 = baz - Delete me

You can see that the value "foo" indeed got spliced out of the array — and the values "bar" and "baz" were *shifted down by one position* to become the new elements #0 and #1.

---

Anyway, the fix for this problem is simply "don't do that":

- If you're using `v-for` with a simple array whose elements have no natural key value, you can just omit `:key` entirely and let Vue decide how to best handle changes to the underlying array.  As long as the contents within the `v-for` loop doesn't contain any form inputs or stateful components or other fancy stuff that doesn't react well to the array being reindexed, it should work just fine.
- Conversely, if you do have a natural unique key available for each array element, use it.  If you don't, but can create one, consider doing that.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Saying that I map the array to contain an unique key called 'id' for each item, which method can be used to remove the "right" (at least UI wise) item?

Comment: And if I don't have that key - what do to instead?

Comment: You can still use your  `deleteColumn()` function just as you've written it. Vue will notice when the indices change and update the `@click` handlers. Or, alternatively, you could replace the array with an object and use the unique keys as the property names, as in `{id01: 'foo', id02: 'bar', id03: 'baz'}`. Then you could reference values directly using their key, and remove them using the [`Vue.delete()`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete) method.

Answer (score 0):

You **should not use index** as the key with CRUD operations since this will confuse Vue when it comes to deleting. The key should be a unique identifier that relates to the data.

You can create a new formatted array of objects on mount with a key generated from the data within the array (note: I haven't tested the code in a browser if there are any mistakes).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="col in formattedColumns" :key="col.key">
      {{ col.value }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      columns: [['position', '30'], ['position', '60'], ['position', '90']],
      formattedColumns: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    let columns = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
      columns.push({
        value: this.columns[i],
        key: this.columns[i][0] + this.columns[i][1],
      });
    }

    this.formattedColumns = columns;
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this `this.$delete(this.columns, index)` which is the same as `Vue.delete(this.columns, index)`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#Vue-delete

Comment: Just try it, everything works well!

deleteColumn: function(index) {
     this.$delete(this.columns, index);
}